# Where I can found driver for HP3940 Printer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, inkjet-printer

I have HP Printer 3940 and given driver doesn't support windows 7 and windows 8. please help me where i can get driver for my printer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe here on this [link](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=445479&cc=us&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=445475) you can find it.
Make sure you chose the right OS and architecture (32/64 bit system)

Regards.